# Making a drop down populate sheet from a database

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sheets in my document. The first sheet’s columns are days (A-C) and the rows are specific attributes for each day (temperature, cloud cover, rain, etc).
On the second sheet, I have a data validation drop down selector, it’s contents sourced from the “Days” strip (A-C, so it displays A-C as options) in sheet one. When I select day C for example, I want all the attributes for that day to populate in cells down the page. It should update depending on which page is selected.
Much appreciated, thank you.

Image: https://ibb.co/DgvnLLc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) to find the column index that corresponds to the dropdown value.
- Use [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) to retrieve the corresponding column data.

```
=OFFSET(Sheet1!B3, 1, MATCH(A2,Sheet1!B3:D3,0)-1, 3)
```

[image]